# Is this possible to encode/decode uploaded file on the fly?

Tags: javascript

Recently I was thinking about building a small, secure service that lets a user upload a file and encodes this file with a public key of the receiver. The key is that I want to do this on the fly, so no encoding before upload but as a part of it. I started digging the Internet but I couldn't find any direct answer.
Is this even possible?

Comment: What do you mean by on the fly?

Comment: Yes, this is totally possible, JS can do lots of stuff on the client side. Your only problem is that your service is not necessarily more secure than transmitting the file to the server - the users will still have to *trust your service* to supply them with the right script that does the encoding.

Comment: "*no encoding before upload but as a part of it*" - where exactly is the difference? What do you consider to be "part of the upload"?

Answer (score 1):

The [Streams API](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6605041225957376) comes to mind ( [TransformStream](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5466425791610880) in particular), but i don't have experience with this new platform feature.

You'd probably still need to build a encode-before-uploading for the other browsers.
That solution is probably good-enough.
But using it as an enchantment could be nice, detecting the feature is trivial:

```
if ('TransformStream' in window) {
```

Answer (score 1):

**You have to perform the encryption before uploading the file.**

I provide a simple example of client side encryption/decryption (using Caesar encryption).

Essentially it uses the `FileReader` API to convert the contents of a file to an `ArrayBuffer`. Using typed arrays (in this case an `Uint8Array`), you can modify every single byte of the original `ArrayBuffer`, and perform your encryption.

Once the encryption is done, you can proceed with the data sending.

```js
let input     = document.getElementById('input');
let img       = document.getElementById('myImg');
let caesarKey = document.getElementById('caesarKey');
let log       = document.getElementById('log');
document.getElementById('encrypt').addEventListener('click',encrypt);
document.getElementById('decrypt').addEventListener('click',decrypt);

// variables to store the image data, a d the encrypted image data
let imgData;
let encryptedData;


// prepare the file reader, and the onload callback
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = e=>{ 
  log.innerHTML='Image ready! Press encrypt button...'
  imgData = reader.result;
}

// declare the file input onchangen handler
input.addEventListener('change', e=> { 
  log.innerHTML='...processing image'
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.target.files[0]);
});

// caesar encrypt function
function encrypt(){
    log.innerHTML='Encrypting...'

    let key = Number( caesarKey.value )
    encryptedData = new Uint8Array(imgData);
    for(let i=0;i<encryptedData.byteLength;i++){
      encryptedData[i] = encryptedData[i]+key;
    }
  
    log.innerHTML='Image encrypted! Press decrypt...'
}

// caesar decrypt function, and image output
function decrypt(){
    log.innerHTML='Decrypting...'

    let key = Number( caesarKey.value );
  
    for(let i=0;i<encryptedData.byteLength;i++){
      encryptedData[i] = encryptedData[i]-key;
    }
  
    // output the image
    var blob = new Blob( [ encryptedData ], { type: "image/jpeg" } );
    var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL( blob );
    img.src = imageUrl;
    
    log.innerHTML='Image decrypted! '

  
}
```

```css
#log{
  padding:5px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="log">--Select a jpg Image--</div>

<input type="file" accept=".jpg" id="input"><br>

Caesar Shift value:
<input type="text" id="caesarKey" value="5"><br>
<input type="button" value="Caesar Encrypt" id="encrypt">
<input type="button" value="Caesar Decrypt"  id="decrypt">
<img id="myImg">
```

Answer (score 0):

For example on the server side you can use next simple code for node.js

```
// Dependencies
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');

const secret = 'password';

/*
*  Crypt file with aes192
* @param {String} fileName to crypt with aes192 alghoritm and secret that contains password
* function create file with name fileName.enc
*
*/
const cryptFile = (fileName) => {
  const cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes192', secret);

  const input = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
  const output = fs.createWriteStream(`${fileName}.enc`);

  input.pipe(cipher).pipe(output);
};

/*
*  Decrypt file with aes192
* @param {String} fileName to decrypt with aes192 alghoritm and secret that contains password
* function create file with name fileName
*
*/
const decryptFile = (fileName) => {
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes192', secret);

  const input = fs.createReadStream(`${fileName}.enc`);
  const output = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);

  input.pipe(decipher).pipe(output);
};
```